# Slow internet connection on one of two KVM guests (debian)

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, slow-connection

My setup:

- Proxmox on the host machine with vmbr0 bridge for guests and a shorewall firewall
- Guests (both KVM not openvz):

  - Windows Server '08
  - Debian lenny

I can download a speed test file on the proxmox host (wget) and on the windows server (firefox) with about 8-10MB/s. But when I download the file with wget on the debian guest it's only 2-3MB/s.
Both guests use the same network bridge, both have 'rtl8139' as the network card in KVM.

Someone knows how to fix that? I want to use the debian VM as a webserver so it needs some bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use kvm you should:

- disable the io scheduler with bootstring elevator=none
- use virtio net drivers

Answer (score 0):

agreed on the virtio drivers. the scheduler I prefer for hosts is deadline though

Besides that, have you checked with tcpdump what is going on underneath the hood?

Comment: deadline is a good guess for the kvm server - but it does not make sense to have a scheduler in the server and in all guests...

Comment: yeah, the guests don't need it. I haven't seen cfq get in the way though, and I have lots of guests on KVM